# How to filter rows from (one to many relation) table based on two columns

Tags: sql-server

Here is the table structure (one to many relation). Each group (T01,T02,T03...) will either have a stamp Number or No Stamp number

[image]

I would like to filter rows from the result set given in figure 1 based on DocType and StampNum field. I want to show all the rows apart from those rows which have docType 4 and StampNum is Null. If there is a StampNum with docType 4 then it should be included.

So result would look like

[image]
I have tried the following sql but its not showing right results.

```
SELECT * FROM EmpDocs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * from EmpDocs b 
        where a.ID = b.ID 
          and b.DocType = 4 and b.StampNum is not null)
```

Comment: Try this updated ... `SELECT * FROM EmpDocs a WHERE docType <> 4 and isnull(StampNum,'') <> ''`

Comment: post it here sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @user1263981 Answer from pit doesn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM Employee a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * from Employee b 
                   where a.ID = b.ID 
                   and b.DocType = 4 
                   and b.StampNum is  null)
```

Comment: If there is a StampNum with docType 4 then it should be included.

Comment: @user1263981 try one more time i updated as you said

Comment: it doesn't include ID 7 where doctype is 4 with the stampNumber. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EmpDocs WHERE DocType <> 4 and StampNum <> ' '
```

StampNum Column don't have null value is having a Empty 
Value

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM employee
  WHERE DocType = 4
    AND StampNum is NULL
)
```

This will select all rows, but exclude the ones were the ID is in the set of rows where `DocType = 4 AND StampNum is null`.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e377d/1) for demonstration.

**Edit:** In fact, you can solve this with only one SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE DocType <> 4 OR (DocType = 4 AND StampNum is not null)
```

If performance might be an issue for you, this will probably be faster than the other solutions, but this is just a guess.
Also, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e377d/3) for demonstration.

Comment: _"this will probably be faster than the other solutions"_ `NOT EXISTS` should be preferred over `NOT IN` (**on SQL-Server**). Not for performance reasons (should be the same plan) but because of issues with nullable columns. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: @TimSchmelter My comment on performance was regarding my second solution, neither using `NOT EXISTS` nor `NOT IN`. Thanks for the article anyway, good to know that `NOT EXISTS` is the preferred way to go.